# Why do I have to change the color scheme multiple times to get it to work?

Tags: vim, neovim

I am trying to set up a different `coloscheme` for my neovim. I'm trying to use [Moonfly](https://github.com/bluz71/vim-moonfly-colors). The problem is, when I set it up, it supposed to look like this:

[image]

Instead of this, it looks like this:

[image]

However, in some strange way that I don't understand, when I change the colorscheme to [PaperColor](https://github.com/NLKNguyen/papercolor-theme) and then to [Rose Pine](https://github.com/rose-pine/rose-pine-theme) (it that order) **before** changing to Moonfly, it works. I mean, I have to do this:

```
colorscheme papercolor
colorscheme rose-pine
colorscheme moonfly
```

and the colorscheme works perfectly.

I don't know if this helps, but if I change the colorscheme to Rose-Pink without changing it first to PaperColor, Rose-Pink doesn't work correctly either.

The terminal I'm using is iTerm.

Is there a way I can use the moonfly colorscheme without changing it first to papercolor and rosepink? I suppose this two colorschemes are changing something in my config that moonfly needs and doesn't change by itself, but I don't know what is this thing.

Comment: Are you loading this as a plugin or just a vim color file? If using as plugin with plug be sure to place it after plug#end. Or consider moving it into the start or after directory. If it's related to your config track it down starting neovim with a bare config and incrementally add/uncomment settings and later plugins until the bug plays up. `nvim -u config` to start with specific config.

Answer (score 0):

Upon loading the previous two color schemes, the requirements for the color schemes are loaded. It might be that those dependencies are the same as the color scheme that you want to use. Make sure that you are following all of the requirements that the color scheme has. The documentation for your color scheme says:

> moonfly is now a GUI-only colorscheme.
> A GUI client or a modern terminal version of Vim or Neovim in a true-color terminal is required.

The documentation then links [here](https://github.com/bluz71/vim-moonfly-colors#true-color-terminals).